# Heroku is using assets that no longer exist in the repo

Tags: css, git, heroku

For my website that I'm hosting on heroku I recently did a change in the color scheme, which involved a little picture that was tiled as a background. I removed said picture, as well as making some other small style adjustments, and my page (locally) looks like this:

[image: Local Version]

The one on Heroku looks like this:

[image: Live Version]

What I noticed throughout the page was that Heroku used some changes, like the removal of some divs that I didn't need anymore, but the style changes were not used. Also, unlike the other questions that are similar to mine, I'm not using Rails. This is a simple html site (using an index.php and composer.json so heroku actually serves it) The changes show up on github, and the activity tab on heroku for the app recognizes the commits. What's going on?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache / tried a different browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dev tools like the Chrome Web Inspector, check on the HTML and CSS being served on the production site and see if your changes are in the code. If your changes are not reflected, try clearing your browser's cache.